# Theming Dialog on API 21 (Lollipop) Android

Tags: android, xml, dialog, themes, android-5.0-lollipop

I am currently trying to theme Alert Dialogs on an android app I am making.
I can theme API 9 (min for app) through API 19/20 (KitKat).

However, I cannot theme API 21 (Lollipop) correctly. I do not like the off-white/light-gray color that is the default theme, so I am trying to make the entire background white.

[image: Screenshot of dialog with default material light theme]

I can only do a certain amount by setting the background of the layout of the dialog to white, and also the button backgrounds to a selector which is white.

There is a strip of space behind the buttons (all across the bottom) that remains the grayish color though. I have tried looking into if I can change it by theming the buttonBarStyle attribute, but haven't had any luck.

Here are some code snippets:

Theme:

```
    <style name="myTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/AlertDialogCustom</item>
    </style>
```

Custom Alert Dialog Theme:

```
    <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:centerBright">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:centerDark">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:fullBright">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:fullDark">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:topBright">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:topDark">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

I have tried some things like this inside the Dialog theme.
Nothing has worked:

```
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarStyle">@style/CustomButtonBarStyle</item>
```

CustomButtonBarStyle:

```
    <style name="CustomButtonBarStyle" parent="@android:style/ButtonBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Found out I needed to use

        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogCustom</item>

instead of alertDialogStyle
Don't know why it made a difference, I would have expected either to work, since Style worked all the way up to api 21.

Comment: You should post this as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out I needed to use

`<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogCustom</item>`

instead of `alertDialogStyle`. Don't know why it made a difference, I would have expected either to work, since Style worked all the way up to api 21.

I am posting this answer well after I had this question, and the solution I wound up coming up with (I may have had other issues with above answer, I don't remember) was re-creating the entire dialog using a layout, and having custom buttons in the layout.